# Magento 2 : How to show only collection filterd data based on any condition?

Tags: magento2, grid

Created grid in Magento 2 admin using UI component and want to filter the grid records before grid load based on any condition. 
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you show your grid xml?

Comment: which grid.xml you want see? UI component?

Comment: what's your data_source dataProvider class?

Comment: This is my data provide class :
[Company]\[Vendor]\Model\ResourceModel\[modelname]\Collection

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter condition in collection for this in grid.php file ::

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('field_name', $value)
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```